# PHP greater than not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want my .icon element to only display when Wordpress menu items are greater than 0, but this isn't working for some reason - it displays even when menu items are 0.

```
<?php
  if (count($my_menu) >= 1) : ?>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon">Menu</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us  output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($my_menu);` at the time when you said that it's empty?

Comment: Check also the documentation about count method : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
if (!empty($my_menu) && count($my_menu) >= 1) : 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon">Menu</a>
endif;
```